# Printing specific pages from a PDF file without user interaction

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

For example I have a 30 page long PDF file located on an internal server. User wants to have a button, that prints only the 5th, 6th, 7th pages of it.

Downloading PDF from URL without user interaction, URL always contains a .pdf file:

```
public void DownloadFileToLocalFolder(string urlToPdf)
    {
        using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
        {
            wc.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            wc.DownloadFile(new System.Uri(urlToPdf), "C:\\Pdf\1.pdf");
        }
    }
```

Printing this file to the default printer without user interaction:

```
public void PrintFile(string path)
    {
        var pi = new ProcessStartInfo(path);
        process.UseShellExecute = true;
        process.Verb = "print";
        var process = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(process);
    }
```

How could I send specific pages to the printer from a PDF file?

Comment: You can't send a file to a printer automatically from a webpage.

Comment: The code is working, the application is sending jobs to the printer which are getting printed successfully.

Comment: Yes, it is sending it to the printer connected to the server, not the client....

Comment: My bad, the application is indeed hosted from my computer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The only way to tell the printer which pages of a file to print is by
>   manipulating Page Settings using a Print Dialog

However,

- that would not be 'silent' since it would show the print dialog
- that would also have to be done in a WinForms/WPF  app, not a web app
- does not use `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()`

**Solution - modify the file before sending it to the printer!**

- Get the PDF as stream, to avoid saving it to disk twice, but you can do that also
- Use a PDF library (such as [itextsharp](https://github.com/itext/itextsharp)) to make a new PDF containing only the desired pages based on your business logic
- Save the resulting PDF that only contains the pages you want
- Then call `PrintFile()` on the modified PDF

*See example:* https://forums.asp.net/t/1630140.aspx

Comment: This will work great. I'll display the generated PDF in a partial view, then the print function will use only that area.

I cant upvote, but at least I can mark as solved. Thank you

Comment: Since the application will be used by many users, generating a PDF each time the button is clicked could lead to document mix-up, or slow application performance.

Comment: That's why I suggested to do it in memory, rather than saving the file. Then you save the file only once instead of twice each time a print is done. The PDF generation isn't a huge deal. Also, the way you have it working, it has to be used by one person at a time since it'll only print from the machine it's running on. Put some thought into also having some clean-up procedure that deletes the files periodically, say nightly, etc.

Comment: Also, if you can take out the 'no user interacton' requirement, then you can avoid saving the file at all, simply download it into a stream, modify it in memory, then send the modified PDF to the browser, and the user can print it. Then no saved files, and only using RAM for the actual PDF processing, then releasing it on to the client.